# How to create and use custom shape, i.e Constant as a drawable shape for GradientDrawable in Android?

Tags: android

GradientDrawable Class in Android allows with the constants(Shapes) like Oval, Rectangle etc. Is there any way to add few more shapes like circle or triangle or any other shape so that we can make its look and feel more attractive.
Also suggest if there is any other Class to be used and the way it is used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pskink I saw ShaperDrawable, but dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 final GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.rect_shape, null);
```